# Convert a single-file Tiddlywiki to a folder for use with NodeJS locally

Tags: tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

I've downloaded a `tiddlywiki.html` file, which I want to host locally with NodeJS for personal use. How do I do that?

I tried `tiddlywiki --load`, but it exited successfully without appearing to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `--savewikifolder` command to actually save the wiki, in addition to the `--load` command to load the HTML file:

```
tiddlywiki --load ~/Downloads/tiddywiki.html --savewikifolder converted_wiki
```

This can then be run with `--listen` to serve the wiki locally:

```
tiddlywiki converted_wiki --listen
```

In my case, this produced the following warning:

> Warning: Plugins required for client-server operation ("tiddlywiki/filesystem" and "tiddlywiki/tiddlyweb") are missing from tiddlywiki.info file

Which I fixed by adding those two plugins to the generated `tiddywiki.info` file:

```json
{
    "plugins": [
        "tiddlywiki/tiddlyweb",
        "tiddlywiki/filesystem",
        ...
```